# How to execute .sql file(BigQuery) from Cloud Function?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

Has anyone tried executing BigQuery script stored in gs://bucket from a Cloud Function?

I could not find any documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Python:

## requirements.txt file

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version
google-cloud-bigquery
google-cloud-storage
```

## main.py file

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import storage
import base64

def execute-sql-scripts(request):
    client = bigquery.Client(project='bigquery-project-id')
    # Read query from GCS bucket.
    gcs_client = storage.Client('storage-project-id')
    query = read_sql(gcs_client,'bucket-name')
    job = client.query(query)
    result = job.result()


def read_sql(gcs_client, bucket_id):
    bucket = gcs_client.get_bucket(bucket_id)
    blob = bucket.get_blob("update-script.sql")
    contents = blob.download_as_string()
    return contents.decode('utf-8')
```